# playframework how to call method from html in href that takes one parameter?

Tags: playframework

I have the following routes

```
GET {company}.dev.alvazan.com/test  Web.test 
GET {company}.dev.alvazan.com/samplepage  Web.samplePage
```

I can go to xxxx.dev.alvazan.com/test just fine UNTIL I add a reference to samplePage.html like so....

```
<a href="@{Web.samplePage()}">TRY ME</a>
```

and of course that is because the method is really Web.samplePage(String company) so that a user can go directly to that web page...but I try changing to one of theses and it doesn't work either...

```
<a href="@{Web.samplePage('${company}')}">TRY ME</a> 
<a href="@{Web.samplePage(${company})}">TRY ME</a>
```

How does one make sure the Web.samplePage is correct in the href above in the html???

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you have already specified the @ symbol, you don't need to then use the $ symbol, as the groovy compiler is at that point expecting code. So, assuming `company` has been passed into the view from the controller, you should be able to do...

```
<a href="@{Web.samplePage(company)}">TRY ME</a>
```

Comment: Just for anyone's information; the following syntax achieves the same thing using the built-in tags: `#{a @Web.samplePage(company)}TRY ME#{/a}`