# PlayFramework2 Link

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm able to create html links the following way:

```
<a href="/about">About Us</a>
```

This will follow the routing for `/about`. But on the following pages (I know it's for an earlier version of Play, but I couldn't find any info for 2.0.1):

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/tags

[playframework how to call method from html in href that takes one parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187114/playframework-how-to-call-method-from-html-in-href-that-takes-one-parameter)

The link is obtained from the routing file. I have the routing for the above link defined as:

`GET        /about                              controllers.Application.about()`

In PlayFramework2, how can I programmatically get the routing to happen by passing in the controller and function name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this in the template:

```
<a href="@routes.Controller.method("param-value")">Link</a>
```

in your case:

```
<a href="@routes.Application.about()">Link</a>
```

also you can use router in the controller with similar syntax:

```
public static Result redirectSomwhere(){
    return redirect(routes.Application.about());
}
```